# Questions about WeakMap and private variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, weakmap

In the book I am reading at the moment, it talks about how we can use WeakMap to enforce privacy with the example code below.

```
const Car = (function() {
  const carProps = new WeakMap();
  class Car {
    constructor(make, model) {
      this.make = make;
      this.model = model;
      this._userGears = ["P", "N", "R", "D"];
      carProps.set(this, { userGear: this._userGears[0] });
    }
    get userGear() {
      return carProps.get(this).userGear;
    }
    set userGear(value) {
      if (this._userGears.indexOf(value) < 0)
        throw new Error(`Invalid gear: ${value}`);
      carProps.get(this).userGear = value;
    }
    shift(gear) {
      this.userGear = gear;
    }
  }
  return Car;
})();
```

I can not understand how such code can truly make gear property private and won't allow access from outside.

it seems that by using

```
carProps.set(this, { userGear: this._userGears[0] });
```

we are hiding userGear and making it private so it can not be accessed.

However, when I use

```
const car1 = new Car("Toyota", "Prius");
console.log(car1);
console.log(car1.userGear);
```

it shows me the result of

```
Car {
  make: 'Toyota',
  model: 'Prius',
  _userGears: [ 'P', 'N', 'R', 'D' ] }
P
```

I am not sure why I could access userGear and got 'P' instead of 'undefined' here where it is suppose to be not accessible.

Probably I am doing something wrong or understood the concept incorrectly.

Can someone please help me to understand the WeakMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter and setter of `userGear` shown in the code is just there to show you how you could communicate between the (private) `carProps` inside the class and the outer scope. The point of the example is to show that the `carProps` variable cannot be accessed, except through the deliberately exposed `userGear` methods. If those methods didn't exist, then after setting the WeakMap in the constructor, the outside consumer of `Car` wouldn't be able to see or do anything with it, eg:

```js
const Car = (function() {
  const carProps = new WeakMap();
  class Car {
    constructor(make, model) {
      this.make = make;
      this.model = model;
      this._userGears = ["P", "N", "R", "D"];
      carProps.set(this, { userGear: this._userGears[0] });
    }
    shift(gear) {
      this.userGear = gear;
    }
  }
  return Car;
})();

const car = new Car('foo', 'bar');
// at this point, at this level of scope,
// there is no way for a user of "car" or "Car" to reference carProps
console.log(car.userGear);
```

For another example that might make more sense, say that the constructor chose a random number that the user of the class had to guess:

```js
const Game = (function() {
  const gameProps = new WeakMap();
  return class Game {
    constructor() {
      gameProps.set(this, { randomNum: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
    }
    guess(num) {
      return gameProps.get(this).randomNum === num ? 'Win' : 'Lose';
    }
  }
})();

const game = new Game();
// at this point, at this level of scope,
// there is no way for a user of "Game" or "game" to reference gameProps
// or to figure out the random number, without guessing multiple times
console.log(
  game.guess(1),
  game.guess(2),
  game.guess(3),
  game.guess(4),
  game.guess(5)
);
```

With the above code, there's no way for the caller of `Game` to figure out Game's internal random number without calling (the deliberately exposed method) `.guess` a few times. (unless `Math.random` gets monkeypatched beforehand...)